# REGEX Code for URL redirect from paramter to direcory

Tags: regex, wordpress, redirect

Im using Wordpress Redirection Plugin and WPML Multi Langue Plugin for my Website. Unfortunatley until today i was using URL Parameters for different languages like "https://example.com/some-permlink-dir/?lang=en" was for for the english version. now i would like to change it to "https://example.com/en/some-permlink-dir/" 
since i got a lot of subpages on my website and the redirection plugin offers regex im wondering how i can tell the plugin that i would love to redirect all the traffic from the url parameters to the directiry version because in dont want to add redirections rules for every single subpage. any idea how i could write the right regex statement ?

Comment: are there other url parameters besides lang? is it safe to assume that lang will be the first url parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Add new redirection window (mentioned [here](https://howarddc.com/understanding-redirection-regular-expressions/))

try source url: `\/(some-permlink-dir)\/\?lang=(\w+)`

and Target URL: `/$1/some-permlink-dir/`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/o5a0BM/2)